# getting a desired layout- android

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, alignment

i know this might be too match to ask but  need help getting the right layout

here is what i want it to look like-
http://s7.postimage.org/4oay4d2sb/layout.png

the things i got stuck on were the spaces and the text view and the alignment of the buttons (pretty much everything)- 
1- is there a way for me to assure the text view will allays be at the same size even when there is no text in it or when there is too match text in it?

2- if there isnt a way to do that can i tell the spaces to fill in the remaining part between the text view and the point i want the buttons to appear?

3- is there a way for me to align the buttons to the buttom to make sure they always stay there at the same place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="qqqqqqqq" />
  </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Toast"/>
        <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Toast"/>
        <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Toast"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

        <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Toast"/>
        <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Toast"/>
        <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Toast"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

        <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Toast"/>
        <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Toast"/>
        <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Toast"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp">

        <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Toast"/>
        <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Toast"/>
        <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Toast"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        >

        <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Toast"/>
        <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Toast"/>
        <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Toast"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        >

        <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Toast"/>
        <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Toast"/>
        <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Toast"/>
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this is great thank you but it still has the same problam i had - if you change the content of the text view the field is being shotend and then all the buttons shift up - i dont want that to happand... at the same time though - i cant use this-
        android:layout_height="80dp"
cause i want it to fit on diffrent devices and doesnt matter what their size is

Comment: @user1486061 see i have made changes to it,as you wanted that particular space though being text length minimum in your layout.

Comment: cool, thats exactly what i wanted .
 just so i understand what you did there-you split the view into many smaller parts and you set the first part to have a permenet size right?

Comment: yes giving particular height to layout will occupy that much space.and according to me if you have given two hours to implement particular thing than take 1:30 hours to think how it can be implemented and rest in implementation.see for the way how it can be divided into such parts which would be easy for us to implement.